# .htaccess RewriteRule help

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying to create a rule.

If anyone could help, I would be extremely grateful.

Request: `domain.com/c/wb.php?p=rs/rs/1tb/25n/ru/rs`

Rewrite to: `domain.com/c/wb/rs/rs/1tb/25n/ru/rs`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this a bit backwards.  The idea behind URL rewriting is that you take a nice neat URL like this (what the user sees):

```
http://domain.com/c/wb/rs/rs/1tb/25n/ru/rs
```

and rewrite it behind the scenes into an uglier but PHP etc. friendlier URL like this (what the server processes):

```
http://domain.com/c/wb.php?p=rs/rs/1tb/25n/ru/rs
```

To do that, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/c/wb/(.*) http://domain.com/c/wb.php?p=$1 [L, NS]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your invaluable help, i try @elmugrat solution but i get an error: Internal Server Error  .....Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.    Thanks

Comment: What else is in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(c/wb)\.php\?p=(rs/rs/1tb/25n/ru/rs)$ $1/$2 [L,NS]
```

Still I'm not sure if you need slash in front of `c/wb` if you're using this in your .htaccess file. You need slash if you're using this in the VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: It will not work -- `RewriteRule` does not work with QUERY STRING **directly**, only with help of `RewriteCond`

Comment: Yes, you are correct here. Still if @joseav wanted the rewrite rule as @elmugrat sees it, our discussion is worth nothing.